# How to compile examples within their subdirectoires instead of typesetdir with l3build?

Tags: l3build

I would like to build/typeset/compile some TeX examples files distributed among some subfolders, using l3build.
Since these are examples, I use the `l3build doc` command.
And I succeeded to compiled them in the `build/doc` folder.
But, for some dependencies between these files and their relative paths, I would like to compile these files within their respective subfolders.

Let's say that my folder is the following:

```
 |- build
 |- pack_examples
   |- exampleA
     |- exampleAmain.tex
     |- exampleAdependency.tex
   |- exampleB
     |- exampleBmain.tex
     |- exampleA-Bdep.tex
 |- sources
   |- mypackage.sty
```

If the `.log` file indicates where the compilation is performed, I would like to obtain the following result with l3build:

```
 |- build
   |- doc
     |- pack_examples
       |- exampleA
         |- exampleAmain.tex
         |- exampleAdependency.tex
         |- exampleAmain.log
       |- exampleB
         |- exampleBmain.tex
         |- exampleA-Bdep.tex
         |- exampleBmain.log
 |- pack_examples
   |- exampleA
     |- exampleAmain.tex
     |- exampleAdependency.tex
   |- exampleB
     |- exampleBmain.tex
     |- exampleA-Bdep.tex
 |- sources
   |- mypackage.sty
```